# Linear array search

Tags: java, arrays

I'm pretty new to java and I'm trying to learn so I'm just wondering how I could preform a linear search through my array.
This is what I've done so far but it doesn't work.

```
public boolean contains(Object elem)
    {
        boolean result = false;
        for(int i=0;i<this.vector.length;i++)
            if(elem.equals(this.vector[i]))
                result=true;
            else
                result=false;
        return result;
    }

    public int indexOf(V elem)
    {
        int pos = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<this.vector.length;i++)
            if(this.vector[i].equals(elem))
                pos=i;
            else
                pos= -1;
        return pos;
    }
```

Comment: Can you show us how it fails? An example, maybe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `contains()` function only returns true if the passed `elem` is the last item in the array.  If you find it, you should `return true` immediately.

Your `indexOf()` method suffers from the same issue.

Comment: @ogward Accepting the answer would be very nice ;)

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a `break` after you've found the element.

Answer (score 1):

Oneliner:

```
Arrays.asList(vector).indexOf(elem);
```

It just creates and deletes one more object (ArrayList) in the memory. Should not be a problem in the most of situations.

Answer (score 0):

You need to break your loop when you find your match.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with that code: in both methods, you always search through the entire array, even if you have found the element already. In both methods, this is the source of a bug (and less importantly: it is not as efficient as it could be).

```
for(int i=0;i<this.vector.length;i++)
    if(elem.equals(this.vector[i]))
       return true;
return false;
```

(and similar for the other method) might be a better implementation.